# SQL converting nvchar to ntext

Tags: sql

What I have is a staging table that is all nvarchar (so i can load it easily).  In my live table i have a bunch of ntext items.  I have the following:

obviously this isnt the whole query:

```
update
     SLTDS_C69_Stdtable
set
    [AARIssue] = convert(ntext, st.[AARIssue]),
    [AttachmentIDs] = convert (ntext, st.[AttachmentIDs])
```

I get this error returned:

types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

ANy idea how to fix this?

Comment: What an ambiguous error message... BTW you use an alias that is not defined but I think you just forgot it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to replace the text or add to it?

INthe first case you don't need to convert at all, just set the filed to the value of the filed inthe other table. INthe second case you need to use UPDATE text.

However, you have a problem in that ntext is deprecated, you should consider converting these fields to nvarchar(max) as soon as possible unless you are still running SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a repeat of this: [How to update a text or ntext field in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204170/how-to-update-a-text-or-ntext-field-in-sql-server-2000)

The live table should use UPDATETEXT?